# Textarea sem barra de rolagem

Tags: html, css

Sempre que você escreve dentro de um textarea, aparece a barra de rolagem para descer e ver o resto do texto.

O que eu quero é que o textarea desça automaticamente, tipo, quando eu estiver digitando dentro do textarea, em vez de aparecer a barra de rolagem, ele vai descendo automaticamente.

Eu estou usando HTML5 e CSS

Comment: Dessa forma: http://jsfiddle.net/hozefa/8fv6e/

Comment: A pergunta é a mesma que a outra, não duplique perguntas, vá na outra pergunta e explique melhor o que precisa se faltou algo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar fazer o "autoResize" com Jquery. Assim a caixa do textarea irá expandir, sem a barra de rolagem.

```
$('textarea').autoResize();
```

Ou outra opção mais simples é definir o scroll como hidden.

```
 height: 75px;   
 overflow-y: hidden;
```

Segue um link com alguns exemplos.[Exemplos](https://css-tricks.com/examples/TextareaTricks/)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a propriedade do `css` chamada `overflow-y: scroll`.
Dessa forma você conseguirá fazer o `textarea` descer automaticamente.

```
#textAreaId{
   overflow-y: scroll;
   resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Esta quase... Quero que o textarea desca automaticamente sem aparecer aquela barra de rolagem!

Comment: Tenta dar um `resize: none;` em conjunto com o `overflow-y: scroll;`.